# Json serializer returns empty string

Tags: json, vb.net, class, json.net

I have a class as below code. and I tried to convert it to XML and JSON but both of them returns empty value : {}

```
Public Class PivotSet
        Public Shared Property selectedlines As Boolean()
        Public Shared Property selectedlabels As Boolean()
        Public Shared Property linescolors As Integer()
        Public Shared Property labelcolors As Integer()
        Public Shared Property linethick As Boolean()
        Public Shared Property labelbold As Boolean()
        Public Shared Property pivotPeriod As String

        Public Sub New()
            selectedlines = {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
            selectedlabels = {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
            linescolors = {16711680, 255, 255, 255, 32768, 32768, 32768}
            labelcolors = {16711680, 255, 255, 255, 32768, 32768, 32768}
            linethick = {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
            labelbold = {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}
            pivotPeriod = "Yearly"
        End Sub
```

and the following code to convert it to XML:

```
        Dim settings As New PivotSet
        Dim x As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(settings.GetType)
        Dim js As New JsonSerializer()
        Dim fs As New FileStream("d:\set.xml", FileMode.Create)
        Dim writer As New StreamWriter(fs, New System.Text.UTF8Encoding)
'serialize to XML
        x.Serialize(writer, settings)
'serialize to json
        File.WriteAllText("d:\Settings.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(settings))
```

But the result for JSON is {} and for XML Also

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PivotSet xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
```

Does anybody can help me about the problems?

Comment: Change all the arrays in List(Of [type]). Add the new values: `selectedlines = New List(Of Boolean) From {True, True, True, True, True, True, True}` etc. Then `Dim myPivot = New PivotSet()
Dim pivotSets = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myPivot)`

Comment: Thanks. but unfortunately it returns empty JSON/XML string again after the changes.

Comment: Have you removed the `Shared` thing from the class properties? Do as described, you'll see that it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Shared from the properties and it should work:

```
Public Property selectedlines As Boolean()
Public Property selectedlabels As Boolean()
Public Property linescolors As Integer()
Public Property labelcolors As Integer()
Public Property linethick As Boolean()
Public Property labelbold As Boolean()
Public Property pivotPeriod As String
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Also. Your answer is also working by removing Shared expression.